# Story gap between Manga Arc 2 and 3?

Tags: re-zero

So I have finished the anime and been reading the manga but after Arc 2 when Subaru and Ram decide to go after Rem it abruptly finishes and Arc 3 starts after the battle with the demon dog. Soo does that mean there is no manga chapters for that fight? Or will it be released later? Or there are the manga chapters but I couldn't find them..?

Comment: I don't know where you are reading this but there are different adsptations of each arc that run seperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Manga For Arc 2 and Arc 3 is published at the same time with different Mangaka

Arc 3,Truth From Zero Mangaka (Daichi Matsue) draw the first ones, A Day in the Capital) also and his work published in Comic Alive.

The 2nd Manga Arc 2, A Week in The Mansion drawn by Makoto Fugetsu is published by Big Gangan

Both are not finished as of my writing (19/10/2016).